# How to convert a hexadecimal string to Uint8Array and back in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I want to convert a hexadecimal string like `bada55` into a `Uint8Array` and back again.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Vanilla JS:

```js
const fromHexString = (hexString) =>
  Uint8Array.from(hexString.match(/.{1,2}/g).map((byte) => parseInt(byte, 16)));

const toHexString = (bytes) =>
  bytes.reduce((str, byte) => str + byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'), '');

console.log(toHexString(Uint8Array.from([0, 1, 2, 42, 100, 101, 102, 255])));
console.log(fromHexString('0001022a646566ff'));
```

Note: this method trusts its input. If the provided input has a length of 0, an error will be thrown. If the length of the hex-encoded buffer is not divisible by 2, the final byte will be parsed as if it were prepended with a `0` (e.g. `aaa` is interpreted as `aa0a`).

If the hex is potentially malformed or empty (e.g. user input), check its length and handle the error before calling this method, e.g.:

```js
const isHex = (maybeHex) =>
  maybeHex.length !== 0 && maybeHex.length % 2 === 0 && !/[^a-fA-F0-9]/u.test(maybeHex);

const missingLetter = 'abc';

if (!isHex(missingLetter)) {
  console.log(`The string "${missingLetter}" is not valid hex.`)
} else {
  fromHexString(missingLetter);
}
```

Source: the [Libauth](https://libauth.org/) library ([hexToBin method](https://github.com/bitauth/libauth/blob/bdc1d67a3181cf6fcfe796a7b4ae36ee3f98af0a/src/lib/format/hex.ts#L37))

Comment: There seems to be an issue in this answer that I've encountered .. i.e

Comment: The condition for throwing the error is wrong, it should be reversed to `if(missingLetter.length % 2 !== 0) {`

Comment: I get a failure in `fromHexString()` if the supplied hex string is zero-length; `match()` returns null rather than a zero-length array in this case, so the call on `map()` fails.

Comment: @MichaelKay – thanks, I added a note about inputs of length 0.

Comment: Beautiful `fromHexString` function :)

Comment: isHex could be tested to just match ```/^(([a-f0-9A-F]){2})+$/``` .

Answer (score 36):

### Node.js

For JavaScript running on `Node` you can do this:

```
const hexString = 'bada55';

const hex = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(hexString, 'hex'));

const backToHexString = Buffer.from(hex).toString('hex');
```

(source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55260916/10149510) by @Teneff, shared with permission)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution in native JavaScript:

```
var string = 'bada55';
var bytes = new Uint8Array(Math.ceil(string.length / 2));
for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) bytes[i] = parseInt(string.substr(i * 2, 2), 16);
console.log(bytes);

var convertedBack = '';
for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
  if (bytes[i] < 16) convertedBack += '0';
  convertedBack += bytes[i].toString(16);
}
console.log(convertedBack);
```

Answer (score 4):

## Browser (mimic NodeJS behavior acurately)

I had a need to mimic the NodeJS `Buffer.from(x, 'hex')` behavior in the browser environment and This is what I came up with.

It's pretty fast when I ran it through some benchmarks.

```
const HEX_STRINGS = "0123456789abcdef";
const MAP_HEX = {
  0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6,
  7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, a: 10, b: 11, c: 12, d: 13,
  e: 14, f: 15, A: 10, B: 11, C: 12, D: 13,
  E: 14, F: 15
};

// Fast Uint8Array to hex
function toHex(bytes) {
  return Array.from(bytes || [])
    .map((b) => HEX_STRINGS[b >> 4] + HEX_STRINGS[b & 15])
    .join("");
}

// Mimics Buffer.from(x, 'hex') logic
// Stops on first non-hex string and returns
// https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.18.1/src/string_bytes.cc#L246-L261
function fromHex(hexString) {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(Math.floor((hexString || "").length / 2));
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    const a = MAP_HEX[hexString[i * 2]];
    const b = MAP_HEX[hexString[i * 2 + 1]];
    if (a === undefined || b === undefined) {
      break;
    }
    bytes[i] = (a << 4) | b;
  }
  return i === bytes.length ? bytes : bytes.slice(0, i);
}
```