# Import raw image data into a script with vite

Tags: javascript, png, svelte, vite

According to the [Vite Docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-string), one can import a file as a raw data string.

In a svelte project I need to use not just the URL, but the whole image data.
As such, I tried to `import image from "@/assets/image.png?raw"`.
However, whatever I try I cannot convert this to a `Uint8Array`. I have tried using `string.charCodeAt(0)`, `string.codePointAt(0)` and all kinds of other stuff.
I expect the first bytes to be `137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10` as that is the [PNG header](https://docs.fileformat.com/image/png/#png-file-header), but it always comes back as `253, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10`. These discrepancies continue through the whole string.

I have no idea what encoding this is in and as such don't know how to decode it into image data again. I previously tried using `fetch()`, but since my origin uses `Basic-Auth` that also didn't work (The credentials change from user to user, and I want to avoid having them to type it in again somewhere else - I use `https://user:password@example.com` as URL notation).

```js
import image from "@/assets/image.png?raw";

let data = Uint8Array.from([..image].map(x => x.codePointAt(0)));
console.log(data);
// [253, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, ...]
```

How can I get the actual image data into my script, without using something like fetch?
The format can be pretty much anything, I use it both as a `Uint8Array` and a `base64` string, and I can convert between the two. I can also convert from a `Blob` / `File`.

Comment: I've made a [proposal to vite](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12366) to add this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raw loader does not appear to be suitable for binary data. When I tried it, I ended up with replacement characters (`�`) in the data.

You can easily write your own plugin that encodes the image however you want, e.g. as a hex string:

```js
/** @type {import('vite').Plugin} */
const hexLoader = {
    name: 'hex-loader',
    transform(code, id) {
        const [path, query] = id.split('?');
        if (query != 'raw-hex')
            return null;

        const data = fs.readFileSync(path);
        const hex = data.toString('hex');

        return `export default '${hex}';`;
    }
};
```

Which can be added in the vite config, e.g.

```js
const config = {
    plugins: [hexLoader, sveltekit()],
    // ...
}
```

Then you can import using a `path/file.png?raw-hex` and [convert the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987784/how-to-convert-a-hexadecimal-string-to-uint8array-and-back-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing how to import assets correct way but I believe using urls is the correct choice. As explained here https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url these will be either inlined as octet streams or as static assets with a changing hash in the name allowing the use of long cache expiry times.

While I also tried using hex strings as shown above, I found it doubled the size of my imported binary file. So I now use:

```js
import binUrl from './file.bin?url'


   ...
   const bin = new Uint8Array(await (await fetch(binUrl)).arrayBuffer())
   ...
```

Comment: Note that this only works if your file is smaller than [assetsInlineLimit](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-assetsinlinelimit), which defaults to 4KB